# Moq for single line multiple property code

Tags: c#, moq

I have these interfaces

```
public interface Interface1 { Interface2 Items {get;} }
public interface Interface2 { Guid? ApplicationTypeId { get; } }
public interface Interface3 { Class1 Item {get;} }
public interface Interface4 { Guid? ApplicationId { get; set; } }
```

A class inherits the first interface

```
public class Class1 : Interface1 {
   public Interface2 Items { get; }
}
```

Another class which consists of few guids

```
public static class ContentTypeIds
{
    public static Guid ContentGuid1 => new Guid("{11798e9d-a167-4cfc-8cfa-9a24fd6caf25}");

    public static Guid ContentGuid2 => new Guid("{7d22f5bb-37fd-445a-b322-2fa1b108d260}");
}
```

I need to unit test the following property

```
private readonly Interface3 _interface3;
public Ticket Current
{
   get
   {
      //This line is very complicated
      Interface4 itemByContentType = _interface3.Item?.Items.GetItemByContentType(ContentTypeIds.ContentGuid2);
      if ( itemByContentType?.ContentId != null )
          return Get(itemByContentType.ContentId.Value);
      return null;
   }
}
```

My test class goes here

```
[Test]
public class TestClass {
    var mock1 = new Mock<Interface1>();
    var mock2 = new Mock<Interface2>();
    var mock3 = new Mock<Interface3>();

    mock1.SetupAllProperties();
    mock2.SetupAllProperties();
    mock3.SetupAllProperties();
}
```

The value for 'itemByContentType' goes null.
Could anyone help me to make it simple and testable as it is getting complicated to test this property? I'm using Moq. I will appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert on Moq, but it looks like its **SetupAllProperties** method simply sets up all the properties to act like properties (i.e. the object it creates has a persistent member which can support GET/SET operation).   If this isn't done, then as I understand it, the properties will still be available, but they'll always resolve to *null*.   This is very handy when preparing the Mock objects, but on its own, though, that doesn't setup the properties with any sort of value.

I think what you should be doing is using Moq's **SetupGet** in conjunction with the **Returns** method to prepare the GET of the Items property with a specific value.

Here is some (simplified) sample code, to demonstrate this:

```
public interface IFoo { Guid? ApplicationId { get; set; } }
public interface IBar { IFoo Items { get; } }

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // SETUP
        // Prepare mocks
        Mock<IFoo> MockFoo = new Mock<IFoo>();
        Mock<IBar> MockBar = new Mock<IBar>();

        // Seting up properties allows us read/write Foo's ApplicationId
        MockFoo.SetupAllProperties();

        // The mocked Foo object should be what's returned when Items is requested
        var expectedFoo = MockFoo.Object;

        // Setup the Bar object to return that mocked Foo
        MockBar.SetupGet(x => x.Items).Returns(expectedFoo);

        // The value written here will be persistent due to SetupAllProperties
        expectedFoo.ApplicationId = new Guid("{7d22f5bb-37fd-445a-b322-2fa1b108d260}");




        // ACTION
        // When the "Items" property is accessed, the IFoo we get should be what we mocked...
        var actualFoo = MockBar.Object.Items;

        // ... and we can read the value set to Foo's ApplicationId
        var actualAppId = actualFoo.ApplicationId;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Steven. My problem got simpler after simplifying my Test code